# What to do about a broken rear derailleur inner cage plate?

Tags: shimano, repair, parts, derailleur-rear

The chain on my road bike got caught in the rear cassette and as it snapped it broke one of the guide tabs on the inner cage plate of my new [Shimano Ultegra 6800-SS rear derailleur](http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/components11/road/ultegra1/rd-6800-ss.html). My two questions are:

1. How safe is it riding with this cage plate, given that it's only a guide tab? A mechanic at my LBS said that I can keep riding for a while, as long as the chain doesn't jump over the cage when I downshift.
2. Where can I get this cage plate without having to buy the entire derailleur?

   [image: image of broken inner cage plate]

Comment: For years derailleurs were built without the tab. If the chain is not too slack nothing will happen.

Comment: The tolerances on higher speeds are getting ridiculous. I'm not sure I'd risk it.

Comment: I discovered some more issues with my rear derailleur, and it's inexpensive relative to the effort to locate and purchase the inner plate, so I'm buying a new. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 5):

The relevant document is [Shimano EV-RD-6800-3608A](http://si.shimano.com/php/download.php?file=pdf/ev/EV-RD-6800-3608A.pdf) (Jun.-2013-3608A), which gives an exploded view and part numbers for each of the parts of the derailleur. For the Shimano Ultegra RD-6800 SS, you're looking for Shimano Y5XH08000 for the inner plate. (This also applies to many of Shimano's other parts to find replacement pieces)

Given that you've invested in Ultegra level gear, I'd not risk it and just wait for the replacement to arrive.

Answer (score 4):

Bike shops will sell you a replacement. If you are in the UK then for example

https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/gear-spares/shimano-ultegra-rd6800-inner-plate-gs-type-y5yc25000/

Comment: Thanks. I actually asked my (US-based) LBS, an authorized Shimano dealer, and they couldn't find the part. They suggested I look for a used RD to grab the plate from there.

Comment: Given that the rear derailleur is about 50 bucks total, I'd just get a new one instead if you're going to go down that route.

Comment: Thst's a good point, and I discovered other issues with the derailleur, so I am buying a new one. Thanks @Batman.